# SSRS Report Server sending report to web client using C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252172.aspx
```

I am using the render method from that article

```
public void Render(
    string format,
    string deviceInfo,
    CreateStreamCallback createStream,
    out Warning[] warnings
)
```

The render method calls the CreateStream

```
private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, 
      Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new FileStream(name + "." + fileNameExtension, 
          FileMode.Create);
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

m_streams = new List<Stream>();
report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);

foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
  stream.Position = 0;
```

If i want the CreateStream method to write a http response object using chunk's how can i achieve it ?

what does the foreach method do here apart from iteration why does it set the stream.Position to 0 ?

Since the report.Render method returns a void and makes a callback to CreateStram and if the image is huge how do i loop over the chunks and return the binary chunks to http response object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything with the results from `RenderStream` as byte[], right. I don't know why the position is set to 0 above however, you could write the image to a temp folder, for example:

```
var image = _service.RenderStream("HTML4.0", streamID, null, out imageEncoding, out mimeType);
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(_physicalTempFolder,streamID),image);
```

Comment: Ross thank you for taking time out and responding to this.However, if the byte array is Huge say 300Mb or so the thread will crash and that is where i wanted to use some other version that did not return a byte[]

Comment: I think this is the default behavior for the "HTML 4.0" device rendering. Thinking out loud...you may be able to have the DeviceInfo.StreamRoot point to a http handler that takes a stream and in conjunction with a custom renderer chunk large files into a temp folder and have that http module stream the image. It would be a pain, however, I don't see a "chunk" size in the HTML DeviceInfo settings.